# Send search query to Actionresult

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, get

I am using Examine in Umbraco 7 to search my site index. It works fine but I wanted to keep track of what people search for by storing search queries in my database. I have set up the `ActionResult` which inserts terms into my table in a`Controller` called SearchRecordSurfaceController.

Now, I have a search box and button in a Razor Partial View like this:

```
@model MyCompany.Models.SearchModel  
    <form action="@Url.Action("GetSearchResults", "SearchRecord")" method="get">
        <input type="text"
               id="searchField"
               name="SearchInput"
               value=""             
               placeholder="site search" />

        <button name="Search" type = submit 
                              value = GetSearchResults 
                              class="btnSubmit">Search</button>
        <input type="submit" 
               value="Search" 
               class="btnSubmit" 
               title="Search website" />  
    </form>
```

I want to send whatever the user types into the search box to my `ActionResult` "GetSearchResults" in my `Controller` "SearchRecordSurfaceController". I know you can send a parameter along with a `Url.Action` like this:

```
@Url.Action("GetSearchResults", "SearchRecord", new {myParam = myValue})
```

but I am not sure how to pass the value from the `searchField` input.

How do I get the text from the user's search into my `ActionResult` method?

Comment: Did you end up getting this to work? I'm not sure how to do almost the same thing...I'm trying to pass the search query "q" of one input form search box to another page in Umbraco as well...

Comment: Yes, it works. The answer by @Ant P below helped me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a string parameter on your action method that matches the `name` of the search input:

```
public ActionResult GetSearchResults(string searchInput) { ... }

<input type="text"
       id="searchField"
       name="searchInput"
       value=""             
       placeholder="site search" />
```

Or, alternatively, a model class with a matching property:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public string SearchInput { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult GetSearchResults(SearchViewModel model) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `FormCollection` type

e.g.

```
public ActionResult SearchRecordSurfaceController(FormCollection form)
{
    var searchText = form["searchField"].ToString();
}
```